# Обновление списка файлов и папок в ListView

Tags: c#

Делаю простой файловый менеджер (аля проводник), в принципе уже почти всё сделал, но понимаю что абсолютно не правильно сделал обновление файлов с текущей папке. Сделал по обычному таймеру очищение списка и запрос на содержание в папке файлов и папок, из-за чего происходит мерцание и другие проблемы, да и вообще мне кажется это абсолютно не правильно.
Как правильно сделать?

P.S. только учусь писать на C# поэтому очень прошу пишите более простыми понятиями.

Comment: Сделайте обновление либо по команде пользователя, либо после активации формы, либо после какого либо события (создание, удаление файла/папки) или же вообще комбинируйте.

Answer (score 1):

Перенес комментарий в ответ и дополнил.
Сделайте обновление в трех случаях:

```
1) По команде пользователя
2) По событию создания, удаления, переименование файла/папки
3) По событию активации формы
```

Я думаю их будет вполне достаточно.

Еще в C# есть класс [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx). У него есть события на различные изменения. Можно подписаться на нужное событие и обновлять список.